# Export mySQL table to OpenOffice spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, command-line, export, date, openoffice.org

I want to export the content of a mySQL table into an OpenOffice spreadsheet. The CSV export does not work for me because the mySQL dates don't have the same format as the OO dates. In phpadmin, the option "Open Document Spreadsheet" in Export tab works perfectly. I would like to do it now in a command line. Is it possible?
regards
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
mysql> SELECT a,b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.text' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM test_table;
```

SELECT ... OUTFILE is the compliment of LOAD DATA INFILE so check that for specific options to make it OO - like.
-> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Format the date in the select statement, i.e: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%W %M %Y');
-> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Thanks John. Am I wrong when I say the date_format function will replace the date type of the date field with a string type? What I was seeking is something that preserves the date type. Of course I can code in the spreadsheet the transformation of the string format in the date format but I just wanted to avoid that. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure Patrick. I'd guess that when PHPmyadmin exports it uses INTO OUTFILE with various options. .  .

Comment: My different attempts with date_format and INTO OUTFILE did not work. I also think like you that PHPadmin uses INTO OUTFILE with various options but I don't know these options that would code the type date in the format recognized by OpenOffice.

Comment: The INTO OUTFILE syntax can be difficult to get right. Have you tried 'str_to_date' i.e set col1 = date_format(str_to_date(@col2, 'format'), 'your format')

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect Base to MySQL as described [here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Connect_MySQL_and_Base)
2. Copy data from Base to Calc as described [here](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=28029)

Good luck!